# I'm trying to code a discord bot and when I'm adding a prefix for the economy it doesn't work and it says keyword "intents" is missing

Tags: python-3.x, discord

```
import discord
import responses
from discord.ext import commands
import json
import os
import random

async def send_message(message, user_message, is_private):
    try:
        response = responses.get_response(user_message)
        await message.author.send(response) if is_private else await message.channel.send(response)

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)


def run_discord_bot():
    TOKEN = 'hiding le token hhahahahha'
    intents = discord.Intents.default()
    intents.message_content = True
    client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
  
    @client.event
    async def on_ready():
        print(f'{client.user} is now running!')

    @client.event()
    async def on_message(message):
        if message.author == client.user:
            return

        username = str(message.author)
        user_message = str(message.content)
        channel = str(message.channel)

        print(f'{username} said: "{user_message}" ({channel})')

        if user_message[0] == '!' or user_message[0] == '/':
            user_message = user_message[1:]
            await send_message(message, user_message, is_private=False)

    @client.command()
    async def balance(ctx):
      await open_account(ctx.author)
      user = ctx.author
      users = await get_bank_data

      wallet_amt = users[str(user.id)]["wallet"]
      bank_amt = users[str(user.id)]["bank"]
      
      em = discord.Embed(title = f"{ctx.author.name}'s DogeBux Balance: ", color = discord.Color.orange())
      em.add_field(name = "DogeBux Wallet", value = "$" + wallet_amt)
      em.add_field(name = "Doge ", value = "$" + bank_amt)

    @client.command()
    async def daily(ctx):
      await open_account(ctx.author)
      
      users = await get_bank_data
      
      user = ctx.author
      
      earnings = random.randrange(101)
      
      await ctx.send(f"You claimed your daily check and got ${earnings} DogeBux!")

      users[str(user.id)]["wallet"] += earnings

      with open("bank.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(users,f)
    async def open_account(user):
      users = await get_bank_data
      
      if str(user.id) in users:
        return False
      else:
        users[str(user.id)] = {}
        users[str(user.id)]["wallet"] = 0
        users[str(user.id)]["bank"] = 0

      with open("bank.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(users,f)
      return True

    async def get_bank_data():
      with open("bank.json", "r") as f:
        users = json.load(f)

      return users

    client.run(TOKEN)
```

So I'm trying to add 'commands.Bot(command_prefix = "/")' but when I add .GroupMixin or join it with "and" it gives an error message:

```
File "/home/runner/uefhewhfowkjfweijk/bot.py", line 22, in run_discord_bot
    commands.Bot(command_prefix = "/")
TypeError: BotBase.__init__() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'intents'"`
```

Comment: And now client.command() doesn't work! I need help! It has a yellow underline under "from discord.ext import commands" saying it's unused.

Answer (score 0):

You are currently initialising a discord.Client class, but for your purposes you should be using the commands.Bot class instead. Bot inherits everything from Client, but gives you the command functionality you are after.
Change:

```
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
```

To:

```
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=intents)
```

As well as this, I noticed you have () after one of your @client.event, which causes another error.
Make sure it is:

```
@client.event
```

You may have to change some other code to make all of your commands work, but with these changes I was able to get your code to actually log into a bot, although I have not tested your commands.